# Making an array with 2 digit numbers in javascript

Tags: javascript

Let's say that i got a variable which it contains the number 19. I want to make an array from it with the following numbers

```
var positions = [ "00", "01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19" ];
```

How is this possible in javascript?

Comment: i know that i if the number is for example 9 i can make it 09 with the following line: `var totalplayers = ("0" + totalplayers).slice(-2);` But i cant build an array with all the numbers from 00 to totalplayers

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267283/how-can-i-create-a-zerofilled-value-using-javascript

Comment: I know that var positions = [00..totalplayers]; dont work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like :

```
var number = 19;
var arr = [];
for ( i = 0; i <= number ; i++ ) {
   arr.push(i < 10 ? ("0" + i.toString()) : i.toString());
}
```

demo : http://jsfiddle.net/Kfnnr/1/

Comment: Or more simply : arr.push ((i < 10 ? '0' : '') + i)

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively:

```
var mynumber = 19,
    myarr = String(Array(mynumber+1))
            .split(',')
            .map(function(el,i){return i<10 ? '0'+i : ''+i;});
```

For zeropadding you may want to use:

```
function padLeft(nr,base,chr){
  base = base || 10;
  chr = chr || '0';
  var  len = (String(base).length - String(nr).length)+1;
  return len > 0? Array(len).join(chr)+nr : nr;
}
// usage
padLeft(1);           //=> '01'
padLeft(1,100);       //=> '001'
padLeft(1,10000,'-'); //=> '----1'
```

**Update 2019**: in es20xx `String.prototype` contains a native `padStart` method:

```
"1".padStart(2, "0"); //=> "01"
//           ^ max length
//               ^ fill string (or space if omitted)
```

Answer (score 1):

essentially you want to pad 0's and the answers here will not suffice and scale when the number is changed.. Probably the better solution would be

```
function padZero(num, size) {
    var s = num+"";
    while (s.length < size) s = "0" + s;
    return s;
}
```

Comment: ?? What do you mean with *will not suffice and scale when the number is changed*?

Comment: well if the number was 20000 then would you write i<10000 and i<1000 etc. I was talking before you updated your answer

Answer (score 1):

Using this example finally solved my own @@iterator function interface issue;
Thanks a lot

```js
var myArray = [];
function getInterval (start, step, end, ommit){
    for (start; start <= end; start += step) {
  myArray.push( start < 10 ? ("" + start.toString()) : start.toString());
  
    }
            }

getInterval(2, 2, 20, 20);

myArray; // __proto__: Array
// (10) ["2", "4", "6", "8", "10", "12", "14", "16", "18", "20"]
myArray[4]; // "10"
```